# Hotjar integration with iframe on wordpress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, iframe, hotjar

I'm trying to integrate hotjar in a wordpress site and works perfectly but the page has an iframe with some important data with need to record the problem is that with I follow the guide that hotjar provides but isn't working as expected, I am getting this part in the recording section where the iframe is.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution you mentioned proposes adding an attribute `data-hj-allow-iframe=""` to the `<iframe>` and declaring (whitelisting) the URL in your Hotjar admin panel

As explained by the guide [1] the recordings of `iframes` has some (many) limitations. One of them is that on the recordings the **JavaScript won't be executed**. Some sites make it an obligatory requirement to have JS enabled in order to show content, what seems to be your case. So eventually you may see mouse movements but no content below.

Think of the Hotjar recordings this way: record any user action and when on playback render the actions **and** render a corresponding site underneath. Which for mostly security reasons is restricted in many ways in iframes. Your "iframed" site is restricted from executing JS when viewing the recording. Sorry to say that but you probably won't be able to do what you want here.

[1] https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011624347-Can-I-track-iframes-inside-Recordings

Answer (score 1):

If you control the other side of the iframe you can add the script there and remove it from the parent frame, you also need to match the iframe URL to the subdomain level with some kind of proxy, otherwise, Hotjar recording won't trigger. The recording inside iframes from the parent frame is limited to static ( non-dependant of Javascript) pages, which are unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Hot Jar will not allow external iFrames to be accessed please see from their docs

”If your iframe is not a third-party iframe and is hosted on your site, you can add an HTML attribute to make viewing the content within your Recordings possible. Movement and input data will still not be captured.”

if your iFrame is 3rd party, which most are, you cannot access it, simple as that.